# Dynamically bind URL params for $http service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-service

How can I dynamically populate placeholders defined in URL string that is used for HTTP requests by AngularJS $http service?

```
var urls = {
    GET_USER: '/api/v1/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}',
    GET_USER_POSTS: '/api/v1/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}/posts',
    GET_USER_POST: '/api/v1/group/{groupId}/user/{userId}/post/{postId}'
};

function getUser(groupId, userId) {
    var url = urls.GET_USER; // build URL with passed params somehow
    return $http.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic function that accepts first argument as URL with placeholders and builds URL string with passed params

```
function buildUrl(url) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        var args = arguments, i = 1;
        return url.replace(/{\w+?}/g, function () {
            return args[i++];
        });
    }
    return url;
}
```

Usage:

```
var url = buildUrl(urls.GET_USER, groupId, userId);
```